# Get full byte array from bytes received from websocket

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, byte

I m using websocket in my windows store app. I use the same code like was in sample Connecting with WebSockets sample (Windows 8). But now I have big problem. I get bytes in readBuffer but server sending bytes in some cycles for example message have 20000 bytes then server send 1000 bytes then again 1000 bytes ..=20000. But problem is while(true) because its stil read bytes and in bytesReceived I get 20000 what is ok but readbuffer after this contain only for example 3000bytes. How I can join bytes array or how I can get result byte array. Second problem is I dont know how big will be message thats means if I try get one array this this array contains on end zeros because byte array is declared for bigger size like is in real.

```
 private async void Scenario2ReceiveData(object state)
    {
        int bytesReceived = 0;
        try
        {
            Stream readStream = (Stream)state;
            MarshalText(OutputField, "Background read starting.\r\n");
            while (true) // Until closed and ReadAsync fails.
            {
                int read = await readStream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                bytesReceived += read;
            }
        }...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a MemoryStream and use the ToArray on it:

```
        byte[] completeBuffer;

        using(MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true) // Until closed and ReadAsync fails.
            {
                int read = await readStream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                if(read == 0)
                    break;

                memStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, read);
                bytesReceived += read;

            }

            completeBuffer = memStream.ToArray();
        }

        // TODO: do anything here with completeBuffer
```

U need to test it, if it works with async/await

Comment: hm but completeBuffer = memStream.ToArray(); is unreachable .(

Comment: I test it again and it doesnt work because ompleteBuffer = memStream.ToArray(); is unreachable. Everything after while} is unreachable,.

Comment: because of the exception ReadAsync gives? Or does it stay inside the while? I updated the answer (see read == 0)

Comment: If the ReadAsync throws an exception, you should move the memorystream declaration outside the try/catch

Comment: no there is not exception. But when while cycle is done compiler go out of method void Scenario2ReceiveData thats mean completeBuffer = memStream.ToArray(); is not processed because the compiler not go there. Example>https://www.dropbox.com/s/25peqbifed8rytw/pr.PNG. Grey text is will never  performed

Comment: I think this is not normal behaviour. Are you sure it doesn't loop endless? It should be breaking-out anywhere. Did you try the if(read == 0)? There is not return/exception.